Problem displaying DB2 data on a CICS Map
According to SPUFI DB2 has a 1047 code page and my terminal is configured for the same code page when connecting to Z/OS through TN3270.
I have developed a Cobol program to display on a SYSOUT the contents of a small DB2 Table and it works just fine. The fields are being displayed perfectly well.
I have written a COBOL/CICS/DB2 program that uses the EXEC CICS declarations and EXEC SQL declarations to retrieve the same data from the same DB2 table as the one used for the Batch program (described in the previous line). The data is retrieved from the DB2 table, but it is being displayed completely messed up on the CICS Map, as if the Code Pages from CICS and DB2 are different.
Example: "NAME         :  +è|+ñ| &áñì|è|"
I changed a few times SYSIN information for CICSA JCL and restarted CICS but I still get the same result. I have tried to set CLINTCP, DOCCODEPAGE, LOCALCCSID and SRVERCP to "1047", but still no success.
Does anyone know what I must do to fix the problem and display DB2 data on CICS map readable?
Thanks
